# Import managed package link directly into Eclipse

Tags: managed-package, eclipse

Is there a way to import a package install link directly into Eclipse? We want to be able to back up each version as a separate project, then archive it in Github.  The process would be simpler if we could import a package directly into Eclipse.

Comment: When you are choosing metadata in Eclipse, you can specify a package to define your metadata components. I'm not sure this will get you what you want though but thought I'd throw it out there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Force.com IDE](http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Force.com_IDE) allows you to select a Package as the project contents, this enables you to download explicitly the contents of the package as described by the package you have uploaded (that referenced by the install URL). Once this download has completed you can take the local files and upload to GitHub for your archive purposes.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is it the current package content list and the current version of each component in the org?

Comment: Yes it is, the package.xml you get, as you can see is the actual Package definition, the components are those from the packaging org so are by definition the current ones.